# child item staying at the same position when parent is moving

Tags: html, css

the problem is i have a navbar with scrolling horizontally now when i hover over with sub this shows child dropdown at correct place but when i scroll and then hover it shows in the last position instead showing under the item

take a look at this

```css
    .each:hover > .sub-menu {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .each {
        cursor: pointer;
        background:white;
    }
    .sub-menu{display: none;}
    .nav .sub-menu > .each > .sub-menu {
        left: 100%;
        top:0px;
    }
    .each:hover {
        background:rgb(194, 194, 194);
    }

    .wrapper {
        width: 250px;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    .nav {
        border:1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="wrapper mr-auto">
    <div class="nav flex w-max">
        <div class="each"><div class="title p-1 px-4 border-l">menu</div></div>
        <div class="each"><div class="title p-1 px-4 border-l">menu</div></div>
        <div class="each">
            <div class="title p-1 px-4 border-l">with sub</div>
            <div class="sub-menu absolute border">
                <div class="each">
                    <div class="title p-1 px-4">sub menu</div>
                    <div class="sub-menu absolute border">
                        <div class="each"><div class="title p-1 px-4 border-l">2nd sub</div></div>                            
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="each"><div class="title p-1 px-4">2nd menu</div></div>
                <div class="each"><div class="title p-1 px-4">2nd menu</div></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="each"><div class="title p-1 px-4 border-l">menu</div></div>            
        <div class="each"><div class="title p-1 px-4 border-l">menu</div></div>            
        <div class="each"><div class="title p-1 px-4 border-l">menu</div></div>            
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `sub-menu` element is absolutely positioned but the parent `each` element does not have relative position to contain it. If it did however then the `sub-menu` would be hidden since you have overflow hidden on the `wrapper`. This is a very old problem that still exists in CSS, you'll need Javascript if you really want that horizontal scroll and the dropdown to coexist.

Answer (score 0):

When you do not set a position property, your subsequent elements will look for the closest parent with one.

so just set `position: relative;` on your `.each` class and change `left: 100%;` to `left: 0;` on your submenu declaration